Is it possible to pass a Apollo Client GraphQL error from the server to the client
I am using Apollo client.
I have a GraphQL error from the Apollo error:
const { data, loading, error } = useyQuery();. I can see (and log) this error?.graphQLErrors on server side. On the client the error is undefined.
Is it somehow possible to pass that error to the client and before rendering the page?

This should be returned automatically in error on the client (which will be an array if there were any errors)

Ok. What could be the issue I only see it on server side and the error differs (server: error array / client: undefined?

Probably because it comes from a hook - it might be undefined while loading is true but gain a value later after loading becomes false.

@MichelFloyd I found something interesting. In the code, inside const client = new ApolloClient we have:
cache: new InMemoryCache(cacheOpts).restore(apolloState). When I remove .restore, I can see the error on client side. But when I navigate to another page and go back with browser back-button, the error is undefined. Do you have an idea? And what is the restore doing. Is that needed?

Apollo Client maintainer here.
While I can't really help you with your specific implementation here, we generally recommend against transporting errors from SSR to the browser, as they could reference internals like env variables that you might not want to leak.
Our recommendation would be to just make the request in the browser again and error there again.

I think I am already doing that
